# Why does node Circle to Polygon module returns oval/ellipse instead of a shape like circle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, npm, geojson

I'm using npm package [circle-to-polygon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circle-to-polygon) and I wrote following code to return a polygon which is approximately like a circle.

```
const circleToPolygon = require('circle-to-polygon');

let coordinates = [28.612484207825005, 77.23574939044147]; //lat, lng

let radius = 311;      
let numberOfEdges = 32;    
let polygon = circleToPolygon(coordinates, radius, numberOfEdges);

let coords = polygon.coordinates;
```

When I used coords and created a polygon shape using Google Maps JS API, it showed a shape like oval (*2 ends were very far from each other, two very near, hope you understand*).

In fact, the different in distances one can say is roughly **4:1** ratio. So it's never a shape closer to circle.

Is there any issue, or is it supposed to do this intentionally?

Answer (score 1):

@Vikas Kumar, this seems to be a tricky issue. I suspect that the way circle-to-polygon orders the coordinates and the google maps apis does, are opposite, at least based on the documentation. You could try one thing. Feed lon, lat (e.g., (77,28)) to  circle-to-polygon api and then when you get the output, reverse them (e.g., (28,77)) and feed to google maps api.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the package in npm says so :

> The GeoJSON spec does not support circles. If you wish to create an
>   area that represents a circle, your best bet is to create a polygon
>   that roughly approximates the circle. In the limit of the number of
>   edges becoming infinite, your Polygon will match a circle.

Comment: I read that. It doesn't mean it will output an ellipse or oval like shape. It will give you a polygon that would be like a circle. Even if you use infinite edges, it will only increase smoothness, not the overall shape.

Comment: This link may provide an explanation : https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2016/02/27/ask-ethan-why-are-maps-of-the-cosmos-oval-shaped/#2d7097bc7af6

Answer (score 0):

@Vikas Kumar, I was just looking at it again. I noticed a mistake in the usage of the  circle-to-polygon API. I think that is the cause of the problem you're facing. Please reverse the coordinates in the call itself.

instead of

```
let coordinates = [28.612484207825005, 77.23574939044147]; //lat, lng
```

try

```
let coordinates = [77.23574939044147, 28.612484207825005]; //lng, lat
```